# Python Shell Add Django Admin User to a Group

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-admin

I am trying to add a user and assign a user to a group. The following works to add the user, but when I uncomment the line indicated, I get the error noted below. How do I get rid of the error so that the user (ur) will be added to the group? Thanks for your help!

```
# This file is named passuserstack.py
# I call it by typing: python passuserstack.py johndoe
# to add a user named johndoe

import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dmt.settings")
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

arg1 = sys.argv[1]

def loginuser(myuser=arg1):
    myuserpw = myuser + 'pw'

    # Check to see if that user exists 
    if ( User.objects.filter(username=myuser).exists() ):
        #do nothing
        mynote = "I am a returning user"
    else: 
        # create the user
        mynote = "I am a new user"
        ur = User.objects.create_user(myuser, 'notkeeping@email.com', myuserpw)
        ur.is_staff = True
        ur.save()
        # assign permissions by assigning to a group
        gp = Group.objects.get(name='NBI_graph_tool') 
        #gp.user_set.add(ur) 
        # when I uncomment the line just above this, I get the error :
        # raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
        # django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady" Models aren't loaded yet.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loginuser()
```

Comment: run your program from django python shell:  python ./manage.py shell

Comment: I tried this: python manage.py shell. Then at the next line >>>passuserstack.py johndoe and I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax that points to the e in johndoe. I am not sure I understood you correctly Joel.

Comment: sorry, I forgot you want to run the program.  maybe you can give file as argument to shell, but I'm not sure

Comment: It seems to work if I add two lines after the os.environ.setdefault....line. These are: import django then django.setup()

Answer (score 0):

As Sandra pointed out in the comments, you have to use `django.setup()`. It is documented at [the Django project site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)